# Facebook Share Link: Force wide image format?

Tags: html, facebook

I'm working on a promotion for a company.

The user writes a testimonial and uploads a photo.  We then generate their story on a page like
www.example.com?id=5

We offer them to "Share" this link to Facebook.  I'm using the usual og: meta tags to pass the title, image and description.

The problem is, Facebook caches url links and images the first time it sees them: likely right after the person just created it.  So when they share it, it takes about 30 seconds for Facebook to cache the image and generate an accurate preview.  So problem #1 the user likely doesn't see this preview during the FB share popout stage ( image is missing but text is correct ) and #2 it often appears on the timeline first as the wide image format version, give it 20 seconds, it swaps to the small shoulder thumbnail.  Obviously, the company would benefit more from the wide format version.  Is there any way I can make this happen?  I'd forego problem #1 if I could solve problem #2.  Though I accept that if the image is too small, facebook has to shoulder the image.

Comment: You have to make sure your image is set in the OG meta tags before anything else.  And use the Facebook Object debugger to force it to scrape new information.

Comment: the image is always passed, it just takes some time for facebook to cache each new link.  I think the debugger would only work in the setting that it's the same link each time

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching